# Save an email.Message object into a file

Tags: python

I am trying to modify emails stored as text files. I first import a message like this :

```
import email
f = open('filename')
msg = email.message_from_file(f)
```

Then, I make all the modifications I want, using the features of the email module.

The last step is to save the Message object (msg) in a file. What is the piece of code that does this ? There seems not to be any simple function like "message_to_file()"...

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Messsage.as_string method](http://docs.python.org/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.as_string) should give you a flattened version of the message that you can write out just as you would any other string:

msg.as_string()

If this doesn't provide exactly the format you want, consider trying the [email.generator](http://docs.python.org/library/email.generator.html) module? If I read things correctly, you should be able to do something like this:

```
generator = email.generator.Generator(out_file)
generator.flatten(msg)
```

Assuming `out_file` is an open and writable file and `msg` is your message.

Comment: @Blair Conrad If I have attachment in my email (say some tar.gz files), what should I do to save this attachment with message in one file only?